# How Can I Get the attribute[special_from_date] from Magento Rest API without Authentication

Tags: rest, magento, attributes

I'd like to get the product attributes including **special_from_date**,**news_from_date** and **special_price** from REST API without the authentication steps(Now these REST Attributes are only available for admin).So that guests can get product attributes info just througth the link **http://me.magento/api/rest/products?categories=42**.Anyone can Help,Please?

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to System -> Web Services -> Rest - Attribute 
Select customer or Guest to choose your desired attribute for the products.

Comment: But when I Select customer and Guest,I couldn't find these options.They just can be found in Admin.